# Feynman Kac Terminal value problem two variables

Tags: stochastic-calculus, finance, differential-equations

So, I need some help to move forward with this problem.

$$
\begin{cases}
\frac{\partial F(t,x,y)}{\partial t}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2 F(t,x,y)}{\partial x^2}+\frac{9}{2}\frac{\partial^2 F(t,x,y)}{\partial y^2}+\frac{\partial^2 F(t,x,y)}{\partial x \partial y}-F(t,x,y)=0 \ \ \ (t,x) \in[0,T) x R^2\\
F(T,x,y)=x^2y\\
 \end{cases}
$$

I have concluded that the C matrix defined as $\sigma*\sigma^T=\begin{matrix}
1 & 1\\
1  &  3
\end{matrix}$

and that $\mu_{1}=\mu_{2}=0$

and that I should solve 
$$F(t,x,y)=E_{t,x,y}[e^{-(T-t)}x^2y]$$

but my problem is to figure out how $x$ and $y$ should look like. 
My attempt was 
$$dX(s)=dW_{1}(s)+dW_{2}(s)$$
$$dY(s)=3dW_{2}(s)+dW_{1}(s)$$
since they should be correlated given the problem, but I'm unsure if I have understood how to define $dX(s)$ and $dY(s)$ properly.

Well, if i preceed with $dX(s)$ and $dY(s)$ as defined above I get

$$F(t,x,y)=E_{t,x,y}[e^{-(T-t)}x^2y]=\\e^{-(T-t)}E_{t,x,y}\bigg[\bigg(x+\big(W_{1}(T)-W_{1}(t)\big)+\big(W_{2}(T)-W_{2}(t)\big)\bigg)^2\bigg(y+3\big(W_{2}(T)-W_{2}(t)\big)+\big(W_{1}(T)-W_{1}(t)\big)\bigg)\bigg]$$

which does not lead me to the correct answer. 
Anyone with some guiding for me?

Comment: Can you specify what the correct answer is supposed to be?

Comment: @DaneelOlivaw Well, i substituted the F(t,x,y) that I received into the PDE, which did not lead to 0.. My book does not provide solutions I'm afraid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with

\begin{align}
dX(s)&=dW_{1}(s) \\
dY(s)&=dW_{1}(s)+\sqrt{2}dW_{2}(s)
\end{align}

The covariance matrix of these differentials is $$\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 3\end{array}\right) \; .$$

Comment: Thanks! 
I try to calculate $F(t,x,y)=E_{t,x,y}[e^{-(T-t)}x^2y]=e^{-(T-t)}E_{t,x,y}\bigg[\bigg(x+\big(W_{1}(T)-W_{1}(t)\big)\bigg)^2\bigg(y+\sqrt{2}\big(W_{2}(T)-W_{2}(t)\big)+\big(W_{1}(T)-W_{1}(t)\big)\bigg)\bigg]=e^{-(T-t)}[(x^2+x\big(W_{1}(T)-W_{1}(t)\big)+\big(W_{1}(T)-W_{1}(t)\big)^2)(y+\sqrt{2}\big(W_{2}(T)-W_{2}(t)\big)+\big(W_{1}(T)-W_{1}(t)\big)\bigg)]=e^{-(T-t)}[x^{2}y+x(T-t)+y(T-t)+\sqrt{2}x(T-t)]$
which is not correct. I use that \big(W_{.}(T)-W_{.}(t)\big)^2=(T-t) and that \big(W_{.}(T)-W_{.}(t)\big)\big(W_{-}(T)-W_{-}(t)\big)=(T-t) as well, but maybe the last one is wrong?

Comment: You forgot a factor 2 when working out the square. And the last term is not there because your two Brownian motions are independent.

Comment: Perfect! I misinterpreted that $W_{1}$ and $W_{2}$ were dependent, when it should be X and Y that are. Now I finally get it, thank you!
(I also realized that C should be 
$$\begin{bmatrix}
    1      & 1 \\
    1       & 9
\end{bmatrix}$$ giving me 
\begin{cases}
dX&=dW_{1}(s)\\
dY&=dW_{1}(s)+2\sqrt{2}dW_{2}(s)
\end{cases}